# where clause in inner join

Tags: mysql

I am generating a query. I have two tables name: flights and destinations.
In a flight table, I have column: id, departure, destination, price, airline, class and in destinations table that i have column: `id, destination, country, region.`

Now I want to get flights detail whose region is `"Europe"`. I am doing `inner join`. My query is this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `flights` 
INNER JOIN destinations ON flights.destination = destinations.destination
where region= 'europe'
```

Its giving me null result. if I remove (`where region= 'europe'`) from my query then it gives me the results of all the columns of flights and destinations.

Please help me out

Comment: Upper/lower case issue?

Comment: no its not the issue

Comment: are you sure that the rows exist in the database?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `flights` 
INNER JOIN destinations 
  ON flights.destination = destinations.destination
where LOWER(region) = 'europe'
```

Comment: But OP says the JOIN alone returns flights. Do LOWER in WHERE instead...

Comment: @jarlh Yeah got confused in order answer fast. Updated the query.

Answer (score 0):

I note that you say `'Europe'` is the region.  MySQL can be case-sensitive, depending on the collations being used for the database and table (but not by default).  So, I would start with comparing the proper case:

```
SELECT * 
FROM flights f INNER JOIN 
     destinations d
     ON f.destination = d.destination
WHERE d.region = 'Europe';
```

If that doesn't work, then strange characters might have crept into the `region` column.  You can try:

```
WHERE lower(d.region) like '%europe%'
```

Comment: its working with lower(d.region) like '%europe%'. could you tell me how i write this query in codeigniter????

Comment: @HarrisKhan . . . A new question should be asked as a *new* question.  This question is clearly not about Codeigniter.  If you change the question, then you will invalidate current answers, which is rude because that can attract downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using an inner join, you can specify the region as part of the join conditions, like this:

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM  `flights` 
    INNER JOIN destinations ON flights.destination = destinations.destination 
        AND destinations.region = 'europe'
```

Does the Flights.Destination value store the Id of the Destination table? You may need to adjust the join to

```
flights.destination = destinations.Id
```